# @angular/pwa - How to customize my webmanifest

Tags: angular, angular-cli, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I have an angular pwa (angular 11.2.8) and I usually generate my production code with

`ng build --prod`

in the dist folder, i can locate the pwa manifest.webmanifest file

now: I need to change two settings of the manifest file (scope and start url) from

```
"scope": "./",
"start_url": "./",
```

to

```
"scope": "/",
"start_url": "/index.html",
```

And I don't want to do it in the `manifest.webmanifest` file, as it is not in VCS

where can I store these settings in order to find them in the manifest file at the next build?

Comment: Can you write an NPM script to copy your manifest after each build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the manifest file is at `src\manifest.webmanifest` (by default), which is (should be, if not already) tracked in the source control. That file is created when adding the `@angular/pwa` package, and should be checked-in.

You can modify that file, and it will be copied over to the `dist` output at build time.